# Translate scratch script to HTML and javascript

Tags: mit-scratch

I am wondering if there already exists a translator to export a scratch project to HTML and javascript or to export a project so it can be played on a tablet.

Comment: http://phosphorus.github.io

Answer (score 4):

As [Scimonster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187556/scimonster) mentioned in a comment, [Phosphorus](https://phosphorus.github.io) (written by Nathan) will run your projects on an HTML5 Canvas and let you export the project to other places.

However, [Sulfurous](https://sulfurous.aau.at) is an improvement to the Phosphorus player and might run projects more accurately to how the Scratch Player would.

Note that both players have issues and might not replicate the projects perfectly.

Comment: But how to package it standalone without needing to run it on a link given by these tools Phosphorus or Sulfurous?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [Scratch HTMLifier](https://sheeptester.github.io/words-go-here/htmlifier/) by [SheepTester](https://sheeptester.github.io/), which generates a HTML file that runs the project. It uses the official [Scratch VM](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-vm) so everything should work the same as in Scratch. Note that variables and ask prompts will look different.

Comment: This doesn't seem so nice. I have a simple dart game simulator but it doesn't work properly in the html version

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Phosphorus or Sulpherous now, since Scratch 3.0 (the current version) allows you to directly play on a tablet from the Scratch website. This is because Scratch 3.0 doesn't need Adobe Flash.

Comment: But I was wondering if it can be packed as a standalone web app at a specific url?

Comment: @jayarjo You can add `/embed` after the project url. For example: `https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/303683408/embed`